# If I keep the flowerpot small

Tags: trees, containers

Let's say you want to grow a tree on your balcony. Will the height of the tree be less, if you use a smaller pot than a larger pot? Let's say on natural ground that tree can grow to 5 meters in height. And let's say my balcony ceiling is 3 meters high. Since its roots will be limited because of the size of the pot, will it grow less in height, than its normal height of say 5 meters? And will it still live normally like that?

In short, the bottom line I want to ask is, does the pot size limit the height of the tree growth because of limiting root growth with respect to the natural ground where the roots can grow without limits?

Comment: I must add I guess, that the tree I want to grow is a cherry tree, native and very easily growing in my climate (Ankara Turkey). It drops leaves in fall and blossoms in spring and hopefully and often gives cherries in summer

Comment: I've grown a rubber plant that's supposed to be over 10 m tall in a pot for over 20 years; it's currently only 1.2 m tall. and thriving. I do nothing special to get it to this height except restrict fertilizers. As your accepted answer notes, each tree species is different, but IMO the larger the pot = the less you have to do regarding pruning, etc. I would not fertilize your cherry tree much after the first year in the pot. But - I COULD BE WRONG. As the accepted answer notes, do some research on cherries, especially if you can find any about growing them in pots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have re-discovered bonsai. Bonsai means grown in a container. It is literally "tray cultivation." Though it covers many types of containers other than trays.

A small container will have a big effect on tree growth.

A small container is not the whole story by any means. In order for a tree to be healthy it must be growing. When we grow trees in containers there are bunches of things we do. One big one is pruning. This involves shaping the tree to the restrictions of the container as well as shaping the tree in desirable fashion. That is, you prune both the visible parts of the tree and the roots.

There are lots of other things like controlling fertilizer, water, and light levels.

Some species of tree will do better in containers than others. Some will thrive when pruned back and shaped, others will not do well. Oak trees are notorious for going along fine for years then just dying for no apparent reason. There are varieties of many types of tree that tend to be smaller and so are easier to raise in a pot. I had a dwarf spruce tree for many years until I made the mistake of trusting it to a friend's care while on vacation.

Pine and maple are extremely popular, but there are many species that are grown.

Your strategy should depend on the specific type of tree you have, and the general size you are interested in. Bonsai come in a large range of sizes from tiny little things that you could hold in your hand up to massive things in pots that are meters wide. And the methods that work for one type of tree are going to fail miserably for other types. For example, some types of trees really don't tolerate being pruned. While others are not really healthy and vibrant unless they are pruned.

Google up the specific type of tree you have and look for the care guidance appropriate to it. If you can possibly find it, get the specific variety of tree.

Comment: Thanks. I must add I guess, that the tree I want to grow is a cherry tree, native and very easily growing in my climate (Ankara Turkey). It drops leaves in fall and blossoms in spring and hopefully and often gives cherries in summer

Comment: Many varieties of cherry trees will take very well to growing in a pot on your balcony. You will still need to read up on the care of the specific variety.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's more complicated than that.

What you want is a larger than normal [Bonsai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonsai):

> Bonsai (Japanese: 盆栽, lit. 'tray planting', pronounced [boɰ̃sai] is the Japanese and East Asian art of growing and training miniature trees in containers, developed from the traditional Chinese art form of penjing (盆景).

The small pot is just the start; you also need to frequently trim new growth and occasionally trim the roots.
Appropriate fertilizing, watering, etc. must also be strictly controlled.

(I suspect, but don't know, that a larger plant, such as you are asking about, would be easier to care for and would be more tolerant of mistakes than the traditional tiny bonsai.)

There are many books, sites, videos, etc. devoted to this hobby art form.

This site alone has over 200 questions tagged [bonsai](/questions/tagged/bonsai).

Comment: Thanks. I must add I guess, that the tree I want to grow is a cherry tree, native and very easily growing in my climate (Ankara Turkey). It drops leaves in fall and blossoms in spring and hopefully and often gives cherries in summer